# How to fix "The tag pwa is disallowed" in AMP pages?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Recently I begin to work for a new enterprise. They need I fix some issues on his AMP pages.
Some script or something is adding a pwa tag to the code. For example:
Original HTML(CKEditor WYSWYG)

```html
<span style="font-family:nunito"><strong>World-class Fertility Treatment at ReproART Georgian-American Center for Reproductive Medicine, Tbilisi, Georgia</strong></span>
```

Result on AMP Page

```html
<span><strong>World-class Fertility Treatment at <pwa class="pwa-mark pwa-mark-done" data-pwa-category="spelling" data-pwa-dictionary-word="ReproART" data-pwa-heavy="false" data-pwa-hint="Unknown word: ReproART" data-pwa-id="pwa-073BFF40B8214D6BF9CF8C5B1D2CDC29" data-pwa-rule-id="SIMPLE_SPELLING" data-pwa-suggestions="Re-proart~repaired">ReproART</pwa> Georgian-American Center for Reproductive Medicine, Tbilisi, Georgia</strong></span>
```

This 'pwa' tags are not allowed on AMP and it causes Google Search Bot errors. Any of you have an idea of what is happening here?
It look like a kind of spelling and writing corrector, but I have no idea what script is doing that.

Best regards.

(Edited) **Important**: The database record contain the invalid tags. I check later on the DB. CKEditor don't show this tag.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is causing by Copy-Paste text from people that use [ProWritingAid](http://www.example.com/)

The possible solutions are:

1. Force Plain Text copy. Not recommendable.
2. Apply removeFormat on
   paste.[CKEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246046/ckeditor-apply-removeformat-on-paste)
3. Clean your data at the moment to save on Data Base / Files /
   WebStorage.

Answer (score 0):

I think PWA used to insert tags into the HTML but it doesn't anymore.
Like Alfredo mentioned, either clean all of your data or clean on access if you have a lot of it.